# Error try to install azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.13.0 in python environment

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I have a problem when I try to install azure-cognitiveservices-speech on my Python environment

When I run the command:

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.13.0
```

The next message is shown:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.13.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.13.0
```

My Python version is 64-bit:

```
python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P')*8)"
64
```

And I updated the pip version to 20.2.4

Do I need to install some pre-requirement?

Comment: What is the version of python ?  you could run `python --version` , is it >=3.5 ?

Comment: My Python version is 3.9.0, I Will try whit a less version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah !

Currently the SPEECH SDK is supported in  Python 3.5 to 3.8, hence the error.  ( & 64 bit)

[image]

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-python

You could refer the above article for the other requirements to run the SDK.

You could download Python Specific version from https://www.python.org/downloads/

[image]

Comment: I tried whit the 3.8.2 version and the package was installed successfully.